# Configure STUN and TURN on My Windows localhost and Linux Server

Tags: node.js, webrtc, stun, turn

i am creating live video streaming application using webRTC , so i need to create my own ICE servers.
i have googled 2 days to find out proper steps for configuring ICE server on my windows localhost to test it out my application , but not able to find it.
please help with any reference or link or video  where i can find steps to follow or package to install for ICE server.
if am wrong anywhere please let me KNOW.
thanks in advance.

Comment: why not using google provided free stun server, and or a free turn server(http://numb.viagenie.ca) ? you would shield yourself from config error and test in real condition (i.e across internet and not on localhost).

Comment: What specific issues are you having in your implementation? If this is to just test your WebRTC app, then use an open server. If you need to implement your own ICE server, then ask a question specifying where you are specifically having an issue and not some generic, please help.

Comment: see this [link](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/)

Comment: @RCBrand This is not for windows!